# bash script is not running when I type $ npm build, in console

Tags: node.js, bash, npm, package.json

I want to write a batch script (`build.sh`) to install dependencies, run front end, and run back end at the same time

**package.json file**

```json
"scripts": {
  "dev": "nodemon server.js",
  "client": "cd client && npm start",
  "start": "concurrently \"npm run dev\" \"npm run client\" ",
  "build": "chmod +x ./build.sh"
},
```

**build.sh file**

```sh
#!/bin/bash

npm run build

npm i aws-sdk body-parser concurrently cors dotenv express joi mongoose multer multer-s3 

cd client
npm i axios bootstrap config jquery node-modules react react-bootstrap react-dom react-scripts redux redux-form redux-thunk web-vitals 
cd ..

npm start
```

I'm not sure what I'm missing to have it run properly?
Thanks in advance!

When I type `$ npm build`, into the command line (in the app's directory of course) I get this:

```
Usage: npm <command>

where <command> is one of:
    access, adduser, audit, bin, bugs, c, cache, ci, cit,
    clean-install, clean-install-test, completion, config,
    create, ddp, dedupe, deprecate, dist-tag, docs, doctor,
    edit, explore, fund, get, help, help-search, hook, i, init,
    install, install-ci-test, install-test, it, link, list, ln,
    login, logout, ls, org, outdated, owner, pack, ping, prefix,
    profile, prune, publish, rb, rebuild, repo, restart, root,
    run, run-script, s, se, search, set, shrinkwrap, star,
    stars, start, stop, t, team, test, token, tst, un,
    uninstall, unpublish, unstar, up, update, v, version, view,
    whoami

npm <command> -h  quick help on <command>
npm -l            display full usage info
npm help <term>   search for help on <term>
npm help npm      involved overview

Specify configs in the ini-formatted file:
    /Users/SebastianRusso/.npmrc
or on the command line via: npm <command> --key value
Config info can be viewed via: npm help config

npm@6.14.5 /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm

Did you mean this?
    rebuild
Sebastians-MacBook-Pro:profile-app-server SebastianRusso$ npm buildd

Usage: npm <command>

where <command> is one of:
    access, adduser, audit, bin, bugs, c, cache, ci, cit,
    clean-install, clean-install-test, completion, config,
    create, ddp, dedupe, deprecate, dist-tag, docs, doctor,
    edit, explore, fund, get, help, help-search, hook, i, init,
    install, install-ci-test, install-test, it, link, list, ln,
    login, logout, ls, org, outdated, owner, pack, ping, prefix,
    profile, prune, publish, rb, rebuild, repo, restart, root,
    run, run-script, s, se, search, set, shrinkwrap, star,
    stars, start, stop, t, team, test, token, tst, un,
    uninstall, unpublish, unstar, up, update, v, version, view,
    whoami

npm <command> -h  quick help on <command>
npm -l            display full usage info
npm help <term>   search for help on <term>
npm help npm      involved overview

Specify configs in the ini-formatted file:
    /Users/SebastianRusso/.npmrc
or on the command line via: npm <command> --key value
Config info can be viewed via: npm help config

npm@6.14.5 /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm

Did you mean this?
    rebuild
```

Comment: npm run-script build?

Comment: Just to be clear, your error message doesn't appear to come from typing `$ npm build`, but `npm build`. `$` is not part of the command, just a convention for representing the user's shell prompt.

Comment: Yes, if i wasn't clear^ that's what I meant to. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

`build` is not a valid CLI command for `npm`. To run the `build` script defined in the `package.json`, do `$ npm run build`.

Comment: thanks, $ npm run build, does make it run. but it only prints: "> chmod +x ./build.sh" rather than load the dependancies and run the app.

Comment: It runs the associated command you've specified in `package.json`. What did you expect it to do?

Comment: Sure, that's because all you've asked it to do is add executable permissions to the file `build.sh`. If you want to run that script as well, replace the definition of `build` in the `package.json`  with `chmod +x ./build.sh && ./build.sh`

Comment: interesting, and thank you that worked. i'm curious as to why you'd have to add "&& ./build.sh" a second time. regardless, it works, so thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

```
"build": "chmod +x ./build.sh"
```

should be:

```
"build": "./build.sh"
```

`chmod +x` just makes the `build.sh` file executable, it doesn't actually run it.

Then to run the build command from npm you have to use `npm run build` like the other answer said.